# Disable snapd.refresh.service on 16.04 to speed up boot (no snap packages in use)

Tags: boot, services, systemd, snap

I run Ubuntu 16.04 but never installed any snap packages, at least not that I would know of any.

Here are my slowest processes at boot:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame | head
      9.057s snapd.refresh.service
      5.058s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      1.126s dev-sdb5.device
       822ms storage.mount
       804ms data.mount
       397ms gpu-manager.service
       390ms apt-daily.service
       363ms systemd-rfkill.service
       334ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B023\x2d3905.service
       251ms accounts-daemon.service
```

Obviously `snapd.refresh.service` is taking a huge amount of time compared to the rest, especially as I have no need for snaps anyway.

How can I disable all snap related stuff to speed my boot time up?

Comment: Would `systemctl disable snapd.refresh.service` work? https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#How_do_I_start.2Fstop_or_enable.2Fdisable_services.3F

Comment: I just tried it on my system and it seems to work. `snapd.refresh.service` doesn't show up when I run `systemd-analyze blame | head`.

Comment: @AlcuinArundel I ran `systemctl disable snapd.*` as the tab-autocomplete did only mention `snapd.refresh.timer`, `snapd.service` and `snapd.socket`, but not `snapd.refresh.service`. I think I won't need any of them at all anyway. Now the entry disappeared from the `systemd-analyze blame` output. Would you post an answer please?

Comment: A tip for others reading this Q&A on my own system using `systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service` (which was taking 10 seconds) reduced `systemd-analyze` from 26 seconds to 16 seconds.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no need to disable it to speed up the boot. This was a mistake on our part, and has been fixed in 2.11, out for updating in the next couple of days. Here is the full change log:

https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/blob/2.11/debian/changelog

Comment: I'm on 16.04.2 and it is now 2017-07-17.  `systemd-analyze blame | head` still shows `snapd.refresh.service` as slowest contributor to boot slowness @ 13.702s.   `snapd`, `snap-confine` and `ubuntu-core-launcher` are all on version 2.26.8.    Is this actually fixed in Ubuntu?

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to disable all snap related stuff. If it is not in use it shouldn't even be there.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [systemd wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#How_do_I_start.2Fstop_or_enable.2Fdisable_services.3F), the command to disable a service and prevent it from starting at bootup is:

```
sudo systemctl disable [foo]
```

so

```
sudo systemctl disable snapd.refresh.service
```

should work in this instance.

Comment: Thanks. I ran `systemctl disable snapd.*` instead though as the tab-autocomplete did only mention `snapd.refresh.timer`, `snapd.service` and `snapd.socket`, but not `snapd.refresh.service`.