# Ubuntu 16.04 takes more than 1min 30s to boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, lenovo, systemd

I recently changed my OS from Windows to Ubuntu but now its taking too long to boot.

I want to know which services I can safely disable to make it boot fast.
I tried running `systemd-analyze blame`, and the output was as follows.

**sda3 is my root partition

```
10.184s apparmor.service
      9.998s dev-sda3.device
      9.964s plymouth-read-write.service
      2.564s dev-loop0.device
      2.539s accounts-daemon.service
      2.484s lightdm.service
      2.422s dev-loop1.device
      2.321s ModemManager.service
      2.268s NetworkManager.service
      1.929s thermald.service
      1.779s systemd-logind.service
      1.672s plymouth-start.service
      1.651s snap-core-1287.mount
      1.458s avahi-daemon.service
      1.364s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-A4EF\x2d203D.service
      1.359s rsyslog.service
      1.286s grub-common.service
      1.124s keyboard-setup.service
      1.095s systemd-udevd.service
       976ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       950ms console-setup.service
       869ms udisks2.service
       848ms gpu-manager.service
       790ms systemd-modules-load.service
       768ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       654ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       591ms binfmt-support.service
       590ms upower.service
       565ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
       559ms networking.service
       543ms systemd-journald.service
       516ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       506ms polkitd.service
       501ms ondemand.service
       497ms speech-dispatcher.service
       484ms snap-core-1337.mount
       470ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
       468ms pppd-dns.service
       464ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       436ms bluetooth.service
       372ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       361ms ufw.service
       351ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       335ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       328ms dev-hugepages.mount
       317ms colord.service
       294ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       277ms systemd-sysctl.service
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have not formatted my complete hard disk and few old partitions from windows are present. Though i have disable auto mount for them. Can they be the culprit?

Comment: This is awfully broad. I'll focus on the top of the list....

Comment: as it was when I saw it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use snap you can [disable snap services](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801077/disable-snapd-refresh-service-on-16-04-to-speed-up-boot-no-snap-packages-in-use)

If you don't use Mobile Broadband (2G/3G/4G) devices you can disable Modem Manager

Comment: After upgrade log changed now.

Comment: Is it safe to disable apparmor.service or plymouth-read-write.service

Comment: You have my apologies,  but with all due respect I have no interest in hitting your moving target. You might find http://askubuntu.com/questions/236381/what-is-apparmor and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth informative. I personally wouldn't disable those wervices.

Answer (score 0):

Many things can increase the length of time a system takes to boot, not just the number of services that are enabled.  For example, is the drive with the Ubuntu OS the first device in the BIOS search order?  Is the drive dual boot? And by "time to boot" do you mean the time it takes until you get the login password prompt or the time until all of the services are done loading?

If the latter, as soon as you get control of the GUI, start a terminal session and run:

top

I also always fire up the system monitor right away to see what's going on.

This will give you a good idea of what the CPU is doing and may make any bottlenecks obvious.  A common slowdown is a delay in connecting to the network, especially in a wireless environment.

You didn't mention your hardware configuration.  Obviously, more RAM is better as is a reasonably robust CPU.  A SSD will typically boot a lot faster than a HDD.

You can get a detailed report on the boot process, as well as any problems, delays and so on, by running:

dmesg

and looking at:

/var/log/syslog

Feel free to PM me directly if you like.